# Tableau: how to filter the row with (one of) the biggest value by each category

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table shown below calculating the mode of the numbers of trucks used for each city across a month.

[image]

I just want the rows of the mode value per each city (if there are two or more modes for a city select the first occurrence for simplicity)

How to do this?

Comment: what is mode you are referring to?

Comment: the most frequent occurences